# reg expression search and replace error

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I am trying to search a string which is the list of groups a user belongs to in unix,

and replace the group `vsifax` or is its a middle or end of the string group the `,` before it with a null value or space whichever is easier

```
$gs =~ s/*,vsifax//;
```

but this returns an error when I try to run the script

```
$ usermove.pl > users.sh
Quantifier follows nothing in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/* <-- HERE ,vsifax/
at usermove.pl line 13.
```

I can't see what the issue would be I have read and re read over a few tutorials on regular expressions and its killing me

Comment: In regular expressions the quantifier (* in this case) follows the atom that it is associated with. So having a quantifier as the first element in a regex is always going to be an error. It would be interesting to hear how you think the error message could be clearer.

Comment: @davorg, to somebody using POSIX REs, he might not be that familiar with what a "quantifier" is. I think a clearer message might be "No pattern before quantifier '*'"

Comment: @davorg - As my confusion came from thinking that the "atom" should come AFTER the "quantifier", It was unclear to me why it mattered that there was nothing before the "Quantifier"

Comment: @Axeman yes that also would have helped, knowing what the quantifier was, I assumed they were called "metacharacters" and had never seen the term quantifier in regex before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I don't think * is needed in your regex

```
$gs =~ s/(,?vsifax)|(vsifax,?)//;
```

Comment: I think it will be because there may be times when there is no `,` in front of `vsifax` and the * matches zero or more occurances of the next character....but I will try

Comment: @ScottC You error is raise because your quantifier * is at the wrong place. Try to replace your regex by mine and tell me what you get.

Comment: ok so my next question is WHY did that work without the * when everything I read says I need the * to match zero or more occurances of the `,`

Comment: @ScottC Typically, * matches 0 or more occurences of the PREVIOUS character.

Comment: @ScottC Your * should have been placed after the comma and not before that's why you get an error when you try to run the script. You use * when there is possible to have 0..* instance of your comma (in your example). Using ? is more efficient because en your case you can have 1 or 0 comma before vsifax

Comment: so for my script to do exactly what I want I have moved the * to after the ,

Answer (score 4):

I guess this command should look like this to work.

```
$gs =~ s/*,vsifax//;
```

should be:

```
$gs =~ s/,?vsifax//;
```

I guess you want to delete the group name and the last comma, right?